# C# How to deserialize json data to a generic basic class uisng System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

```
public class BaseRequest : IRequest
{
    public string Command { get; } = "";
}

public class GetRequest : IRequest
{
    public string Command => "get";

    public string Key { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class SetRequest : IRequest
{
    public string Command => "set";

    public string Key { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Now here's a json data string, I need to convert it to the base class to determine which command it has.

```json
{
    "Command" : "get",
    "Key" : "key1"
}
```

And I assume the code below would work.

```
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BaseRequest>(jsonData);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Command);

if (obj.Command == "get") {
   var obj2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GetRequest>(jsonData);
   // ...
} else if (obj.Command == "set") {
   var obj2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SetRequest>(jsonData);
   // ...
} else {
   Console.WriteLine("Unknown command");
}
```

But acturally the `obj`'s Command is an empty string, and finally the program falls into the last `if` branch...

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why you deserialize the data multiple times. Couldn't you simply serialize it once to a class with the required properties, and use this class to see what the properties is set to? Or am i missing something crucial

Answer (score 6):

Thats because the `Command` property in `BaseRequest` is readonly (you haven't declared the setter for it). You need to modify it to:

```
public class BaseRequest : IRequest
{
    public string Command { get; set; } = "";
}
```

More info in "**Why Encapsulation**?" section of https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_properties.php

Or if you don't want to expose `set` publicly you can use `[JsonInclude]`

```
public class BaseRequest
{
    [JsonInclude]
    public string Command { get; private set;  } = "";
}
```